# Why does pyinstall raise import error. The python code runs fine by itself?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a .exe file from my python code using pyinstaller, but I keep getting an import error. I don't understand why. The code works fine when run in spyder. I installed pyinstaller correctly because I was able to make an .exe from a simpler program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
117229 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
117530 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbconvert.py"...
117547 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbformat.py"...
117556 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-notebook.py"...
119487 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of you imported modules require DLL that were not located by pyinstaller. Locate them on your PC (somewhere within your Python install) and then add --paths= to your build command